# Make WPF-control shared

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, controls, shared

I'm trying to access Label from another class's method running in background thread with the help of MainWindow Class's Public Shared Sub like this:

```
    Private Delegate Sub ProgressReportInvoker(ByVal progressStr As String)

    Public Shared Sub ProgressReport(ByVal progressStr As String)
        If MainWindow.Label.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() Then
            MainWindow.Label.Content = progressStr
        Else
            MainWindow.Label.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                            New ProgressReportInvoker(AddressOf ProgressReport),
                            progressStr)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Call from another class is below:

```
MainWindow.ProgressReport("Sample text")
```

But I have this error on "MainWindow.Label":

> Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

I noticed that if I declare Label in MainWindow.g.i.vb as Public Shared than error is gone:

```
#ExternalSource ("..\..\MainWindow.xaml", 11)
    <System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields")>
    Public Shared WithEvents Label As System.Windows.Controls.Label

#End ExternalSource
```

But this file is generated automatically from the *.XAML file so it takes previous look when I compile the code.

Is there any way to make control shared in *.XAML file or may be there are any alternatives of making my task possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access the instance of the `MainWindow` and not the type itself:

```
Public Shared Sub ProgressReport(ByVal progressStr As String)
    Dim mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of MainWindow).FirstOrDefault()
    If mainWindow.Label.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() Then
        mainWindow.Label.Content = progressStr
    Else
        mainWindow.Label.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                            New ProgressReportInvoker(AddressOf ProgressReport),
                            progressStr)
    End If
End Sub
```

> I tried this before but problem is in multitasking. I can't access the form from another thread without some special moves which I don't know about

You can only access a UI control in the thread on which it was originally created:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub()
                                                          Dim mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of MainWindow).FirstOrDefault()
                                                          mainWindow.Label.Content = progressStr
                                                      End Sub))
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried this before but problem is in multitasking. I can't access the form from another thread without some special moves which I don't know about.

Comment: May be I need to do this with invoker or something like that

Comment: You can only access a UI control in the thread on which it was originally created. Use the dispatcher. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

It is very bad practice to use anything global (shared/static). Use instance of class or other mechanism (Dependency Injection, messaging, events, etc.) for communication between independent classes.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Can you give an example please?

Comment: How to use instances is basic thing you must know from the start and one example is from mm8. Dependency injection and messaging are advanced techniques that are not suited for absolute beginners and often requires 3rd party framework. Start with some research about what DI is, for example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection